# Inserting information from one mysql table to another

Tags: java

I am writing a program that will take in a student ID and verify if that ID exists in a mysql table. If it does exist, I would like to take the entire row that it exists in and copy that row to another table. Currently the program will just copy all rows in a table to the other. Any help appreciated. I have inserted a snippet of code below.

```
try {
    String compareText = IDField.getText().trim();

    if(compareText.length() > 0){
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simlab","root","password");
        System.out.println("Connected to database");

        Statement stmt1     = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1       = stmt1.executeQuery("select * from students where LUID='"+IDField.getText()+"' ");

        boolean isPresent = rs1.next();

        if (isPresent)
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simlab","root","password");
            System.out.println("Connected to database");

            int rows = stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO skills(ID_Student,LUID_Student)SELECT ID, LUID FROM students");

            if (rows == 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("Don't add any row!");
            } 
            else 
            {
               System.out.println(rows + " row(s)affected.");
               conn.close();
            }

            //System.out.println("Already exists!!");
        }
```

Comment: Do both tables reside in the same database, or are they in different databases, as the title suggests?

Comment: Both tables are in the same database. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could all do that in a single SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO <Dest-Table>
(SELECT * FROM <Src-Table> WHERE ID=?);
```

It will only copy rows that exist.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's due to this line:

```
int rows = stmt1.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO skills(ID_Student,LUID_Student)SELECT ID, LUID FROM students");
```

As, if that line is parsed, the `SELECT` statement has no `WHERE` clause, and will therefore get every row, and therefore insert everything.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

With Prepared statements

```
        String sql = "INSERT INTO abc"
                + "(SELECT id1,id2 FROM pqr)";

        ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);


        int rs = ps1.executeUpdate();

        if (rs > 0) {

            update = true;

        } else {
            update = false;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (ps1 != null) {
                ps1.close();
                ps1 = null;
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
                con = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return update;
```